# Having Trouble reading JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am new to Anjular.Js and is having trouble reading a .JSON file (todo.json) saved in the server. I have basic express server and all my static files are saved within the 'public' folder. I can access the todo.json file directly form the browser.

I am fairly new to Java Script and any help will be appreciated.

Here is code for the jsdemo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
 <head >
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Java Script Demo</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myApp = angular.module("demo", []);

myApp.controller("demoCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
var promise = $http.get("/todo.json");
promise.success(function (data) {
$scope.todos = data;
  });
});

</script>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->   
</head>

 <body ng-controller="demoCtrl">
 <H1>This is the javascript demo file</H1>
 <div class="panel">
<h1>To Do</h1>
<table class="table">
<tr><td>Action</td><td>Done</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="item in todos">
<td>{{item.action}}</td>
<td>{{item.done}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<!--
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
-->


<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/todoApp.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for my server.js
    //server.js

```
//Modules===================================================
var express=require ('express');
var app=express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var methodOverride=require ('method-override');


// set our port
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; 

// parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 

// parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); 

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

// override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request. simulate DELETE/PUT
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); 

// set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
    });


 // start app ===============================================
 // startup our app at http://localhost:3000
 app.listen(port);               

// shoutout to the user                     
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);

// expose app           
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: What is exact problem you are facing?

Comment: make sure your content-type header is set to application/json or I don't think angular will parse it correctly

Comment: I was expecting to see the data shown in the table, but the table rows are empty in webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my directory structure for the Node.js Express application:

```
expressTest
├── public
│   ├── css
│   │   └── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── angular.js
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   └── todoApp.js (this script is currently empty)
│   ├── todo.json
│   └── views
│       └── index.html
└── server.js
```

The versions for Twitter Bootstrap and Angular.js are the same as those you specified on your posted ***jsdemo.html***. I downloaded them to the project using ***wget*** and your URLs.

The index.html file contains the HTML you put here as ***jsdemo.html***. The ***server.js*** code is exactly as you had posted it when I read it.

My ***todo.json*** file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "action": "Action #1",
        "done": false
    },
    {
        "action": "Action #2",
        "done": true
    },
    {
        "action": "Action #3",
        "done": false
    },
    {
        "action": "Action #4",
        "done": true
    }
]
```

I installed al ***node.js*** requirements. I am using ***node.js*** version ***0.10.35***.

```
npm install express
npm install body-parser
npm install method-override
```

Then, from the command-line console, I ran the server:

```
node server.js
```

Given all these conditions, the example works. I entered the URL in my browser's address bar:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

The table shows the data as desired:

[image: Web page with data showing]

---

> Maybe you have a problem with your ***todo.json***'s syntax. That
>   happened to me (I added an extra comma at the end and data didn't show
>   on the page). Please edit your post to include that file's contents,
>   if you need more help.

---

**UPDATE:**

Your JSON syntax is:

```
[
    {
        action: "Buy Flowers", 
        done: false
    }, 
    {
        action: "Get Shoes", 
        done: false
    }, 
    {
        action: "Collect Tickets", 
        "done": true
    }, 
    {
        action: "Call Joe", 
        done: false
    }
]
```

You need to specify property names inside double quote symbols, like this:

```
[
    {
        "action": "Buy Flowers", 
        "done": false
    }, 
    {
        "action": "Get Shoes", 
        "done": false
    }, 
    {
        "action": "Collect Tickets", 
        "done": true
    }, 
    {
        "action": "Call Joe", 
        "done": false
    }
]
```

Additionally, my install of express gives out this error message on the command line:

```
express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead server.js:27:13
```

You may want to use the new syntax for that deprecated function for future code.

Comment: Hi Trimegistus, my json file looks like this: [
{action: "Buy Flowers", done: false},
{action: "Get Shoes", done: false},
{action: "Collect Tickets", done: true},
{action: "Call Joe", done: false}
]

Comment: The syntax is your problem. JSON specification requires object property names to be surrounded by double quotes. It should look like this: [ {"action": "Buy Flowers", "done": false}, {"action": "Get Shoes", "done": false}, {"action": "Collect Tickets", "done": true}, {"action": "Call Joe", "done": false} ]. That way it will work. Please, mark my answer as correct, so I can get the reputation points, if you liked my effort.

Comment: Dear Trimegistus,I will definitely mark answer as correct. However, I do want you to know that I truly appreciate your time and effort. It was bugging me for a day and I was stuck. You helped me tremendously.

Comment: Dear Trimegistus, just accepted your answer. Would like to connect with you on google plus.--Golam

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. I am not sure about how to connect with you on Google+, without publishing sensitive information here. I am a newbie using SO and Google+.

Comment: if you have Google+, then just add me. my email gmoinuddin92@gmail.com. Just like to know a fello developer who is working on Angular--Golam

Comment: Added you to my stackoverflow circle in Google+.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your server view engine uses curly braces `{{ }}` as well as angular.

1. You may try to override angular binding expression symbols

```js
var myApp = angular.module("demo", []).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol("[[").endSymbol("]]");
});
```

and then in `HTML`use

```html
<td>[[item.action]]</td>
```

2. Or you may prefer to use `ng-bind`

```html
<td ng-bind="item.action"></td>
```